# Reverse image distortion

Tags: image-processing

Say I've the following image
[image: distorted image]

which is a circle and a square capture by a camera positioned 30° far from the ground.
This the scene from an orthogonal POV:

[image]

This is the camera:
[image]

[image]

Is it possible to reverse the distortion in order to obtain the second image (orthogonal POV) from the first one (distorted image) without knowing the camera angle?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

To inverse a perspective transformation, also known as homography, you need to identify 8 parameters. For this you need to know the (X, Y) coordinates of four points both in the original and undistorted image.

A possibility is to use the four corners of the square, but this won't be very accurate. Alternatively, use two corners and the tangency points of the lines from these corners to the circle.

[image]

If you don't know the relative sizes of the square and the circle and their distance, you are a little stuck.